# Unable to compile flutter app on new setup

Tags: flutter

I have newly setup the flutter, but the sample app does not compile.
Flutter doctor also show everything is setup properly.

Following is the error:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on HTC Desire 820G PLUS dual sim in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...                                              1.1s
Resolving dependencies...                                           2.0s
Unhandled exception:                                                    
Crash when compiling package:hello_world/main.dart,                     
at character offset null:                                               
null:4314624: indicated size does not match file size at                
#0      BinaryBuilder.fail (package:kernel/binary/ast_from_binary.dart:98:5)
#1      BinaryBuilder._indexComponents (package:kernel/binary/ast_from_binary.dart:425:15)
#2      BinaryBuilder.readComponent (package:kernel/binary/ast_from_binary.dart:453:36)
#3      ProcessedOptions.loadComponent (package:front_end/src/base/processed_options.dart:391:10)
#4      ProcessedOptions.loadSdkSummary (package:front_end/src/base/processed_options.dart:329:32)
<asynchronous suspension>                                               
#5      generateKernelInternal.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/kernel_generator_impl.dart:71:36)
<asynchronous suspension>                                               
#6      withCrashReporting (package:front_end/src/fasta/crash.dart:122:24)
<asynchronous suspension>                                               
#7      generateKernelInternal (package:front_end/src/kernel_generator_impl.dart:58:10)
<asynchronous suspension>                                               
#8      kernelForProgram.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/kernel_generator.dart:48:28)
<asynchronous suspension>                                               
#9      CompilerContext.runWithOptions.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:134:20)
<asynchronous suspension>                                               
#10     CompilerContext.runInContext.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:122:46)
#11     new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:224:31)                 
#12     CompilerContext.runInContext.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:122:19)
#13     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)                         
#14     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)                  
#15     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)                        
#16     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)                         
#17     CompilerContext.runInContext (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:121:12)
#18     CompilerContext.runWithOptions (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:132:10)
#19     kernelForProgram (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/kernel_generator.dart:47:32)
<asynchronous suspension>                                               
#20     compileToKernel (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:309:27)       
<asynchronous suspension>                                               
#21     FrontendCompiler.compile.<anonymous closure> (package:vm/frontend_server.dart:359:56)
#22     new Future.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:176:37)  
#23     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1120:38)                         
#24     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)                  
#25     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:923:7)             
#26     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:963:23)
#27     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)                         
#28     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)                  
#29     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:947:23)
#30     Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:21:15)
#31     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:382:19)   
#32     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:416:5)
#33     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:12)


#0      BinaryBuilder.fail (package:kernel/binary/ast_from_binary.dart:98:5)
#1      BinaryBuilder._indexComponents (package:kernel/binary/ast_from_binary.dart:425:15)
#2      BinaryBuilder.readComponent (package:kernel/binary/ast_from_binary.dart:453:36)
#3      ProcessedOptions.loadComponent (package:front_end/src/base/processed_options.dart:391:10)
#4      ProcessedOptions.loadSdkSummary (package:front_end/src/base/processed_options.dart:329:32)
<asynchronous suspension>                                               
#5      generateKernelInternal.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/kernel_generator_impl.dart:71:36)
<asynchronous suspension>                                               
#6      withCrashReporting (package:front_end/src/fasta/crash.dart:122:24)
<asynchronous suspension>                                               
#7      generateKernelInternal (package:front_end/src/kernel_generator_impl.dart:58:10)
<asynchronous suspension>                                               
#8      kernelForProgram.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/kernel_generator.dart:48:28)
<asynchronous suspension>                                               
#9      CompilerContext.runWithOptions.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:134:20)
<asynchronous suspension>                                               
#10     CompilerContext.runInContext.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:122:46)
#11     new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:224:31)                 
#12     CompilerContext.runInContext.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:122:19)
#13     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)                         
#14     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)                  
#15     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)                        
#16     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)                         
#17     CompilerContext.runInContext (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:121:12)
#18     CompilerContext.runWithOptions (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:132:10)
#19     kernelForProgram (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/kernel_generator.dart:47:32)
<asynchronous suspension>                                               
#20     compileToKernel (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:309:27)       
<asynchronous suspension>                                               
#21     FrontendCompiler.compile.<anonymous closure> (package:vm/frontend_server.dart:359:56)
#22     new Future.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:176:37)  
#23     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1120:38)                         
#24     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)                  
#25     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:923:7)             
#26     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:963:23)
#27     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)                         
#28     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)                  
#29     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:947:23)
#30     Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:21:15)
#31     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:382:19)   
#32     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:416:5)
#33     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:12)

Compiler failed on /home/sagar/Documents/aviabird/hello_world/lib/main.dart

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                

* Where:                                                                
Script '/home/sagar/development/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 665

* What went wrong:                                                      
Execution failed for task ':app:compileflutterBuildDebugArm'.           
> Process 'command '/home/sagar/development/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:                                                                  
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org                              

BUILD FAILED in 2s                                                      
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         3.0s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Flutter doctor output:

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.7.8+hotfix.4, on Linux, locale en_IN)
    • Flutter version 1.7.8+hotfix.4 at /home/sagar/development/flutter
    • Framework revision 20e59316b8 (2 weeks ago), 2019-07-18 20:04:33 -0700
    • Engine revision fee001c93f
    • Dart version 2.4.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.1)
    • Android SDK at /home/sagar/Android/Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.1
    • Java binary at: /home/sagar/development/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b16-5323222)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)
    • Android Studio at /home/sagar/development/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 38.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 183.6270
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b16-5323222)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.36.1)
    • VS Code at /usr/share/code
    • Flutter extension version 3.3.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • 192.168.56.101:5555 • 192.168.56.101:5555 • android-x86 • Android 7.1.1 (API 25)

• No issues found!

Comment: I see that you are trying to run on physical device `HTC Desire 820G PLUS dual sim`.. did you try it on emulator to see if it compiles there ?

Comment: Yes the emulator also have the same issue

Comment: I think the issue occurred due to prefetching the development binaries during flutter setup:
`flutter precache`

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33390 github issue resolved the problem :)

Answer (score 4):

It seems the cache folder for your flutter installation is broken.

You can do steps below in Terminal command line :

`rm -rf /Users/XXX/flutter/bin/cache` (XXX is Mac user)

`flutter doctor -v`

`flutter run --release`

p/s : [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33390)

Comment: @ch271828n `flutter pub get`

Comment: oh I am not asking you to choose one :) I said that to help other people who face same problem as me. In my case it is a pure dart command line lib so i guess actually the latter works

Answer (score 1):

Just had a similar issue. In my case there was a type in one of the imports.I had "F" instead of "f" in one if the import files. Just double check all the imports (cases, spaces, underscores, etc) thoroughly .